# Where is the mention of 'Chanting Rama three times is equal to chanting 1000 names of Vishnu'?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, scripture, puranas, rama

In the ending part of  Vishnu Sahasranaam Stotra these verses are recited:

> पार्वत्युवाच :
>   केनोपायेन लघुनां विष्णुर्नामसहस्रकम् ।
>   पठ्यते पंण्डितैर नित्यं श्रोतुमिच्छाम्यहं प्रभो ॥ 26 ॥ 
>   
>   *pArvatyuvAcha: 
>
>   keno pAyena lagunA vishNor nAma sahasrakam | paTyate paNDitair nityam shrotumicchAmyaham prabho ||* 
>   
>   Parvati said "O lord what is the short method to recite Vishnu Sahasranaam (if I am not able). What is to be chanted for it?"
>   
>   ईश्वर उवाच 
>   **श्रीराम राम रामेती रमे रामे मनोरमे । 
>
>   सहस्रनाम तत्तुल्यं रामनाम वरानने ॥** 27 ॥
>   
>   *ishwara uvAcha: 
>
>   sri rAma rAma rAmethi rame rAme manorame | sahasranAma thatthulyam rAma nAma varAnane |*
>   
>   Ishwara said " **O beautiful one!, Chant Rama Rama Rama which rejoices the mind. It is equal to thousand name of Vishnu**"

The above verses aren't found in Mahabharata where Bhishma recites Vishnu Sahasranaam. From where are these verses taken ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These verses are found in **Uttar Khanda of Padma Purana** in chapter 71. These verses are the last two verses of that chapter.

> Parvati Said:
>   330. if I am unable to recite every day these thousand names of Visnu, then tell me, O bull-bannered god, that name, by which I shall get that fruit (obtained by the recital of Visnu's thousand names). 
>   
>   Mahadeva said: 
>   331. **O you beautiful one, O you charming one, (recite) 'Rama, Rama, Rama'. The thousand names are equal to that.**
>  
>   *[Chapter 71 Vishnu's One Thousand Names]*

Comment: I was about to comment it but you already wrote an answer.

Comment: You are actually helping others. This is quiet a famous statement which shows the power of name of **RAMA**  but very few people know where it is.

Comment: Great, post such question answer it will really help others .... : )

Comment: Can you please give the link for the verse in Padma Purana ? Also the link for the english version.