# Do i need to regret for my bad deeds or sins before undergoing Upanayana?

Tags: yagnopavitam

I am desirous to undergo upanayana ceremony in one of the sanathana dharma sanstha.. So I don't know at all that any body underwent Upanayan in our caste.
Before I undergo such ceremony, do I need any regret god or prayaschitta? If not, will there be any harm to my family?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE. Please generalize it and make it more clear.

Comment: Are you a Brahmin by birth?

Comment: Am Kshatriya maratha by birth and heard  that Chatrapati Shivaji was also dvija which was granted by Gaga bhat from Varanasi.

Comment: What is your gotra? If upanayanam is not common in your family,then it is probably not ordained for your caste. Regardless, your gotra should tell you whether you are eligible for upanayanam or not.

Comment: Kaushik gotra, will this help me to know  the required information

Comment: @moonstar2001 Every person from first three varnas is eligible for Upnayana(if he is in age limit as prescribed in Dharma Shastras) regardless of his Gotra.

Comment: @Yogi - gotra is the foremost indicator of varna. Also the gayatri for the 3 varnas is different. The gayatri chanted by a brahmana is 24-letters long, that by a kshatriya is 18 - letters long and a vysya's gayatri is 16- letters long. Don't know if people these days are aware of these distinctions. The 24-lettered mantra is chanted openly by everyone these days.

Comment: @Aryan  do you know your pravara? I do believe it is a dwija gotra but I cannot be sure.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Its not gyatri it is known as savitri in common, Kshatriya savitri is in trisbtubh metre and is known as trisbtubh, vaishya savitri is in jagati metre and is known as jagati. Also trishtubh is 4x11 44 syllable metre and Jagati is 12x4 48 syllable metre. The most popular savitri is gyatri for brahmanas.

Comment: @Yogi The words gayatri and savitri are used interchangeably in most cases.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes you need to do penance before Upnayana.**

> He, whose father and grandfather have not been initiated, (and his two ancestors) are called 'slayers of the Brahman.'
>
> If they wish it (they may perform the following) expiation;
>
> In the same manner as for the first neglect (of the initiation, a penance of) two months (was) prescribed, so (they shall do penance for) one year. 35
>
> Afterwards they may be initiated, and then they must bathe (daily).

[Apsthambha Grihya Sutra 1.1.1](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe02/sbe0204.htm)

> For as many years as there are uninitiated persons, reckoning (one year) for each ancestor (and the person to be initiated himself),
>
> (They should bathe daily reciting) the seven Pâvamânîs, beginning with 'If near or far,' the Yagushpavitra, ('May the waters, the mothers purify us,' &c.) the Sâmapavitra, ('With what help assists,' &c.), and the Âṅgirasapavitra ('A swan, dwelling in purity'),
>
> Or also reciting the Vyâhritis (om, bhûh, bhuvah, suvah).
>
> After that (such a person) may be taught (the Veda).

[Apastambha Grihya Sutras 1.1.2](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe02/sbe0205.htm)

---

**Harm to family, No**
In fact vedic karma(Karma prescribed for everybody in vedas) is always purifying and Bhadra(good/auspicious), you don't need to worry about affecting family members.

> Acts of sacrifice, charity and penance are not to be given up; they must be performed. Indeed, sacrifice, charity and penance purify even the great souls.
>   [BG 18.05](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-5/)

So purify yourself and get ready to attain supreme position in lotus feet of Lord.

If the penance is not done your karma will be affected.

---

**If you don't have time, you have to resort to other means**

Since there is limited time for Initiation of Different Dwija Varnas.

> There is no dereliction (of duty, if the initiation takes place), in the case of a Brâhmana before the completion of the sixteenth year, in the case of a Kshatriya before the completion of the twenty-second year, in the case of a Vaisya before the completion of the twenty-fourth year. (Let him be initiated at such an age) that he may be able to perform the duties, which we shall declare below.

I suggest that you should consider the [Sharanagati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saranagati) to lotus feet of lord([BG 18.66](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-66/)), since I've assumed that you don't have 12 years time period to do all the penance.

The sin is equated to Brahmahatya so you can also resort to the [penance for Brahmahatya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11344/how-to-remove-bramhahatya-sin).

Or you can consult any scholar or acharya, they can help you with initiation by quickly performing Penances.

You can consider [rama nama japa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13537/where-is-the-mention-of-chanting-rama-three-times-is-equal-to-chanting-1000-nam), it equals 1000 Vishnu Sahasranama.

Answer (score 3):

First of all only the three dvija(Brahmin,Kshatriya,Vaisya) castes have the Upanayana samskara.Now, even if i assume that you are born in a family belonging to any of the 3 castes its clear that your  family is not following the traditions since many generations.

In those cases the the persons belonging to that family are considered as having lost their caste and it(the caste) can not be recovered  even by Samskaras.

From the book [Hindu Dharma](http://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part17/chap12.htm):

> **If the Gayatri has not been chanted for three generations in the
>   family of a Brahmin, its members lose caste (they cease to be
>   Brahmins).** The quarter where such Brahmins live cannot be called an
>   "agrahara". It is perhaps not yet three generations since Brahmins
>   gave up the Gayatri. So they still may be called Brahmins.
>
> In the same way if the Brahmin family has not performed sacrifices for
>   three generations its members will be called "Durbrahmanas",
>   degenerate Brahmins. Even though degenerate the label "Brahmin" sticks
>   to them. There are prayascittas (expiatory rites) by means of which
>   the corrupted Brahmins will be remade true Brahmins. **But there is no
>   such hope for a Brahmin in whose family Gayatri has not been chanted
>   for three generations. A member of such a family ceases altogether to
>   be a Brahmin and cannot be made one again. He is just a "Brahmana-
>   bandhu", a kin or a friend of Brahmins. The same rule applies to
>   Ksatriyas and Vaisyas with regard to the Gayatri mantra; they become
>   "ksatriya-bandhus" and "Vaisya-bandhus" respectively.**

**About "Hindu Dharma" :**

> "Hindu Dharma" is a book which contains English translation of certain
>   invaluable and engrossing speeches of [Sri Sri Sri Chandrasekharendra
>   Saraswathi MahaSwamiji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrashekarendra_Saraswati) (at various times during the years 1907 to
>   1994).

So,IMO upanayana is not recommended for you.

Comment: There are many Kshatriya and Vaishya varnas in India which have stopped Upanayana. Do all these people lost their Varna?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes, i think they are called by the name Vratyas in scriptures

Comment: @TheDestroyer BTW,u believe that castes are determined by gunas only..In that case what is the importance of Samskara then?..this is of course off-topic here but i'm curious to know..

Comment: Yes. I'm skeptical of these rigid rules. I think these smritis or Dharma Sastras need to be updated. For suppose by God's grace if a "vedic revolution" occurs in India and Vedas are taught in school, 3 Dvija Varnas would opt for Upanayana. In that case few people are allowed to read Vedas which is chaos again. So, i think most of these rules don't apply to today's world.

Comment: @The destroyer Ok So,Chandrasekhara Saraswati is wrong then..but what i asked is in Guna based caste system what is the role of samskaras ?In Hinduism samskaras are crucial..

Comment: I didn't say Sri Chadrasekhar Saraswati was wrong. Who am i to say he was wrong? Dvijas have two births. One from womb and other from Spiritual enlightenment. [Jabala Upanishad](http://www.vedarahasya.net/jabala.htm) says "Self is the sacred thread." I believe this was how Ancient India followed later it was modified.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Sri Chandrasekhara Saraswati is saying that Dvjas lose their caste  if they don't chant gayatri for just 3 generations..and u are saying that u are sceptical about whether dvijas lose their castes even if they have entirely stopped Upanayana..His opinions are based on Scriptures which u want to be updated..His opinions and urs are in opposition..that's y i said so..

Comment: @TheDestroyer And in any case I'm curious to know what role do samskaras play in guna-based caste system?..That was actually my question to you..

Comment: @Rickross This is horrible for me

Comment: Nothing is horrible. You can always take other Guru Diksha from good sampradayas. Upanayan is not the only samskara. @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury