# Is each of Vishnu's 1000 names from the sahasranama of equal potency?

Tags: vishnu-sahasranama

I think some Purana says saying Rama's name 3 times is equivalent to reciting the entire Sahasranama.  The Hare Krishnas also have a similar claim regarding the "hare krishna" mantra.  There is a Puranic story that saying "narayana" on your death-bed grants you liberation, regardless of however many sins you have committed.

As far as I know, only these three names have been singled out this way.  Is that correct?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19815/why-are-the-names-of-lord-krishna-and-lord-rama-superior-to-the-name-of-lord-vis

Answer (score 3):

In [Padma Puraana, Uttarakhanda, Chapter 71](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%AC_(%E0%A4%89%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83)/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A6%E0%A5%AD%E0%A5%A7)

> महादेव उवाच ।
>   राम रामेति रामेति रमे रामे मनोरमे ।
>   सहस्रनाम तत्तुल्यं रामनाम वरानने ॥ ३३१॥
>
> **Shiva said-**
>   **ShreeRaama, Raama, Raama , this itself merges(Rama) one in Raama who is beautiful faced and pleasing to mind.**
>   **This Raama naama is equivalent to SahasraNaama of Vishnu.**

So Raama naama is most powerful Maheshvara Shiva himself has said it.

Thanks @Tezz for providing correct reference.

Comment: The above quote is not from Mahabharata it's from Padma Purana, I discuss it here;https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13537/where-is-the-mention-of-chanting-rama-three-times-is-equal-to-chanting-1000-nam

Comment: @Tezz okay . I had read it from Sanskrita documents which gave it as Mahabharat. It shall be edited. Thanks